# Convert json data from firebase to structured format to run big query

Tags: json, database, firebase, google-bigquery, structured-data

I am new to databases. I have data on firebase in the form of json and I have to run bigquery on it . For this reason I want to convert it to a structured database. Which is the best way to do that ? I want to do it in realtime.

Comment: Do you want to connect BigQuery to Firebase or do you have the the files and just qant to load it on BigQuery?

Comment: I have files on firebase and want to use bigquery on them, so want to connect bigquery to firebase.

Comment: but cani run bigquery directly on json ?

Comment: You can run BigQuery in json files. In your case I think you should look at the export options to send your data directly to BigQuery. You can not link BigQuery to your json files in Firebase directly

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you , i forgot to mention that i wanted that to happen in real time.i.e new data added to my db should be added in bigquery automaticatically

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking forward to send your `Firebase` data to `BigQuery` you should take a look at [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en). Here you can find how to link your `Firebase` project to `BigQuery`

As you can see in the link above:

> You can export Google Analytics, Crashlytics, Predictions, Cloud
> Messaging, and Performance Monitoring data to the BigQuery sandbox
> free of charge (Sandbox limits apply).
>
> With the BigQuery sandbox integration, you have access to:

- > Data from Google Analytics App and App + Web properties
- > Data from Google Analytics for Firebase
- > Details from Crashlytics fatal and non-fatal crash events and stack traces
- > Raw Predictions data Detailed Cloud Messaging data
- > Details of each captured Performance Monitoring event Learn more about upgrading from the Sandbox and BigQuery

I hope it helps

Comment: The poster didn't explain what data they want to move - if it was Firestore, this is another alternative: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export